# Can I query ContentItems using tags in SharePoint 2010 API?

Tags: 2010, rest, soap, social-tag

I am experimenting with [SharePoint 2010 REST Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) and [SharePoint 2010 Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx) to retrieve content based on certain Tags.

Is there a way to retrieve content based on social tags in SharePoint web services?